# Rails 2.3.5: How do I add an :id field to a namespace?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces, routes

I want to have an admin area.
So I wrote:

```
map.namespace "admin" do |admin|
  admin.resources :cities 
  admin.resources :links
end
```

But I would like to the admin area for a specific location.
I am looking for something like:

```
map.namespace "admin/:location_id" do |admin|
  admin.resources :cities 
  admin.resources :links
end
```

what would be the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
map.with_options(:path_prefix => "admin/:id", :name_prefix => "admin_") do |admin|
  admin.resources :cities 
  admin.resources :links
end
```

You can remove `:name_prefix` if you want